# Javascript - If condition in regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I would like to get a valid Javascript regular expression.
This expression works fine except with Javascript. I think it is because Javascript does not support lookbehinds.

My approach: `(?(?!\\{)(\{))`. I want to match all brackets `({)` except those with a backslash in front of it `(\{)`.

Do you have an idea how I can create a valid Javascript expression?

Valid example `function{`

invalid example: `function\{`

Comment: Provide some valid and invalid matching examples.

Comment: Why not changing the lookbehind with a lookahead?

Comment: I tried it, but had some mistakes in my expression. That is why I tried this way.

Comment: [Looking for this???](http://regex101.com/r/tH7gL8/1)

Comment: No, if there is \{, it does not match the bracket ({). It only matches the bracket if there is no backslash as the previous character. I want detect the brackets. Brackets with a backslash should not be detected.

Comment: You didn't look carefully. It is giving you match in capture group #1 ONLY when there is NO \ before `{`

Comment: I know what you are trying. But this is wrong. You only have one line. There are two cases: abc\{ or abc{. If there is abc\{, there is no match, if there is abc{, it matches the {. Your example matches \{ or {. But it has to match { except \{.

Comment: In absence of lookbehind this is well established regex pattern. To decide it is a match or not all you need to do is check whether there is `match[1]` or not for the given line.

Comment: Did you try along `.*[^\\]({)` [RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/vJ4iW5/1)?

Answer (score 0):

```
.*[^\\]({)
```

works on [RegExPal](http://regexpal.com/) though not for JavaScript on [RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/zQ1kQ3/1).